# React-Native: Unhandled JS exception module "555"

Tags: react-native

I started a sample app with React-Native. I am getting an error "Unhandled JS exception:Requiring module "555", which threw an exception.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wZmt.png)

Answer (score 0):

typically this happens when you `require` or `import` something. Are you relying on an external dependency, are you using an image or trying to import your own component defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart `npm` server.  `npm start`

or `react-native start`

Answer (score 0):

I was using old `syntax` (from online course video).

Using below `syntax` solved the problem:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```